# Table of TextBoxes isn't displayed as deisred

Tags: asp.net, controls

I am adding texboxes into a table (type Table) but I can't add them. I can't add more than one cell to each row, any idea?

```
TextBox[] tx = new TextBox[10];
        TableCell[] tc = new TableCell[10];

        TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tx[i] = new TextBox();
            tc[i] = new TableCell();
            tc[i].Controls.Add(tx[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tr[i] = new TableRow();
            tr[i].Cells.Add(tc[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            Table1.Rows.Add(tr[i]);
```

It comes out like 10 rows each having only 1 cell

Comment: What do you want the output to be? 1 row with 10 cells?

Comment: no, it has to be 10 X 10

Comment: Are you storing the textboxs, cells, and rows because you need access to them after you have inserted them into the table?

Comment: yeah indeed. i'll store it in a datatable later

Comment: you store the controls in the db? or the data you are putting into the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells has to be distinct: I need to create 100 cells not only 10!

```
TextBox[] tx = new TextBox[100];
        TableCell[] tc = new TableCell[100];

        TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            tx[i] = new TextBox();
            tc[i] = new TableCell();
            tc[i].Controls.Add(tx[i]);
        }

        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tr[i] = new TableRow();
            for (int j=0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                tr[i].Cells.Add(tc[x++]);
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            Table1.Rows.Add(tr[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need an inner loop on this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    tr[i] = new TableRow();
    tr[i].Cells.Add(tc[i]);
}
```

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    tr[i] = new TableRow();
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
       tr[i].Cells.Add(tc[x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are not set up to give you a 10x10 table

```
Table table = new Table();
TableRow tr = null;
TableCell tc = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    tr = new TableRow();

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        tc = new TableCell();

        tc.Controls.Add(new TextBox());

        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    }

    table.Rows.Add(tr);
}
```